# No bass on Dell XPS 9500

Tags: sound, dell, alsa, xps

So I've gone through a lot of the internet and still cannot find anything that would help me.

This is an issue with all Linux distros. It only works with Windows. So the issue is this: there is no bass on my Dell XPS 9500. I have actually 2 of these computers and both have the same issue. Do people just accept that there is no bass when using Linux with Dell XPS lineup? I saw some guy did kernel edit for 9510 model, but quick try did not show any results (never dealt with kernels, so idk if I did anything correctly as I couldn't find any tutorials on how to apply, plus didn't want to install random kernel patches on my personal PC so had to do weird stuff).

I have attached a screenshot of alsamixer, showing that bass-speakers are at 0 and cannot be increased. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDPFC.png)

I probably tried every possible configuration on hdajackretask, but didn't have any luck.
Is there anything to do?

Comment: You may need to use an OEM kernel (includes specific support and settings for the sound chip) and/or use additional kernel parameters. Unfortunately I'm not the person to answer your question.

Comment: Since Dell does support Ubuntu on some of its models you may try asking them.

Comment: I noticed that spdif is muted on one channel. Have you tried unmuting this? Also, `00` just shows that it's not `MM` which is muted. `00` is not muted and `MM` is muted.